# In Python, is it preferable to call static methods using the class or an instance?

Tags: python, performance, static-methods

You can call Python static methods either from the class itself or from an instance of a class. Is one better than the other?

For example:

```
class Arthur(object):

    @staticmethod
    def wages():
        return 1

    def __init__(self, b):
        bank_balance = b

    def im_rich1(self):
        money = self.bank_balance + sum([self.wages()] for i in range(0,365))
        return money

    def im_rich2(self):
        money = self.bank_balance + sum([Arthur.wages()] for i in range(0,365))
        return money
```

Testing with `timeit` suggests no (noticeable) time difference.

Comment: Please make sure your code is runnable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. If you use the class name, the behavior of the function that uses this call could not be changed in inheriting classes. If you use self instead, classes that inherit this one and override the static method will be able to change the function's behavior.

Comment: True, and certainly something that would make one choose one over the other. But for many (most?) use cases this is just not going to be relevant.